# link_to within Option Value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, hyperlink

I am trying to find out if I can use a link_to performing an Ajax request within an option value tag

```
<option value="<%= link_to 'Manage Sandpiper Posts', posts_path(:type => 'Sandpiper'), :remote => true %>">Sandpiper</option>
```

Because an option value tag only accepts text the output is invalid at the moment and the link obviously doesn't work

What i want to achieve is that upon selecting the option the request is carried out

Does anyone have any ideas how to get around this or what the correct syntax would be if this is possible?

EDIT

I already make this Ajax request from within a dropdown menu when the viewport is in desktop size and it works fine, I achieve this by

```
<%= link_to 'Sandpiper', posts_path(:type => 'Sandpiper'), :remote => true %>
```

Firebug returns params of

```
type = sandpiper
```

the GET request is

```
GET posts?type=Sandpiper
```

This all works fine and the url stays as localhost:3000/posts and my results are returned

Now when i am in mobile view using the select value the returned params are the same as is the get request, difference is the url in the address bar goes to

```
http://localhost:3000/posts?type=Sandpiper
```

and there are no results returned.

controller

```
def index
@posts = Post.all
@tynewyddpost = Post.tynewydd_posts
@woodsidepost = Post.woodside_posts
@sandpiperpost = Post.sandpiper_posts
@outreachpost = Post.outreach_posts
@companypost = Post.company_posts
@staffpost = Post.staff_posts
```

end

index.js.erb

```
<% if params[:type] == 'Tynewydd'  %>
$('#newsResults').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'tynewyddposts') %>');
<% end %>

<% if params[:type] == 'Woodside'  %>
$('#newsResults').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'woodsideposts') %>');
<% end %>
```

I did try changing my controller to match that of @SybariteManoj but that did not work either, though i think im doing the same thing, just in a different way

Comment: any particular reason for the markdown? Would be helpful if you backed it up with a reason rather than just a markdown

Comment: what behaviour do you want to achieve?

Comment: On clicking the option it will change the value of the drop down so why not just use `onchange` event for dropdown for the ajax call.

Comment: would you like to provide an example of what you mean?

Comment: I am not sure why the partials are not being returned, May be showing controller and view(js.erb) code help us understand the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to edit Viktor's answer but it will not be visible until peer review it. So I adding the changes here.

```
<select onchange="follow_link(this)">
  <option value="<%= posts_path(:type => 'Sandpiper')%>">Sandpiper</option>
  <option value="<%= posts_path(:type => 'Outreach')%>">Outreach</option>
  <option value="<%= posts_path(:type => 'Tynewydd ')%>">Tynewydd </option>
  ...
</select>
```

**Changes** Passed this as parameter to the function. and change the value of the option.

```
follow_link = function() {
  var url = $(this).val();
  $.get(url);
}
```

**changes** Modified the function name and the variable url.

Now to answer your second question, you can have something like this in your posts#index action:

```
def index
  @type = params[:type]

  if @type.blank?
    @posts = Post.all
  else
    @posts = Post.where(:type => @type)
  end

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

and add a new file `index.js.erb` under your views/posts directory with content something like:

```
<% if @type == 'Sandpiper' %>
  $('#some_container_id').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'some_partial')")
<% elsif @type == 'Outreach' %>
  $('#some_container_id').html("<%= escape_javascript(render 'some_other_partial')")
<% else %>
  so on...
<% end %>
```

Comment: ok just to update i am now getting No route matches [GET] "/Sandpiper" when clicking the sandpiper link

Comment: what url are you using for ajax call? shouldn't it be `/posts?type=Sandpiper`?

Comment: Well i tried @ViktorTron way, see last comment in his answer, I will have 6 option values altogether, each calling different request, so sandpiper, outreach, tynewydd etc. so i cant explicity use Sandpiper in the function can I? Hope that makes sense, appreciate your help by the way, thank you

Comment: i already have a index.js.erb file doing exactly the same thing as you say, which is great. will try the controller code now

Comment: still nothing being returned from the ajax call

Comment: Check in firebug what is being returned in the console.

Comment: i marked as answer as you got me closer than i originally was plus learned a few things on the way, though still not completely working, same problem

Answer (score 2):

i assume the request is a GET with no formdata, you only use the select input to choose a url, but you want behaviour as if the selected url was 'clicked':
using jquery:

```
<select onchange="follow_link(this)">
<option value="<%= posts_path(:type => 'Sandpiper')%>">Sandpiper</option>
...
</select>
```

then your onchange function:

```
follow_link = function() {
var url = $(this).val();
$.get(url);
}
```

Comment: yes its a GET request, just showing different content. I will give this a try later, i was just confused as i didnt think i could pass a link_to within a option value, though I guess the function takes care of this? Thank you by the way

Comment: @Richlewis This is kinda what I meant. But with just a few changes.

Comment: a link_to will just create an aref within option (escaped), which is not what you want. escaping may still be an issue. anyone?

Comment: Yes. That can be a probable issue. But I think you can just pass `Sandpiper` as value and create your url in your javascript file.

Comment: How would that look? @SybariteManoj

Comment: thanks @SybariteManoj, accepted first edit, kept path as value tho, curious if it works

Comment: will update as soon as i have done it later tonight, thanks both

Comment: in the javascript code, you have wrong function name @ViktorTrón

Comment: ok so tried this way aswell, and when you click sandpiper it goes to http://localhost:3000/posts?type=Sandpiper but no content is loaded (ie the requested content by Ajax

Comment: that will be another question. our mission accomplished ;)

Comment: ok, thanks for your help then :) look forward to seeing you on the next question :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have :onclick=>"some_function()" instead of :remote=>true.Then in put id on the link and in application.js get the link and get the form that you want to submit and send the form.

**UPDATE**

try with this in application.rb:

```
 jQuery(function($) {
   somemethod();
  });
```

function somemethod() {

```
jQuery("#id_of_the_option").bind("click", function() {
  //do something with the content
});
```

}

Comment: thanks for your answer, but i still have the issue of using  a link_to in an option value dont I. Should i just use a normal href link and then use jquery to fire an Ajax request with .click(function()

Comment: I think I have not understand you. This option is from a form and you to submit the form with ajax when this option is selected?

Comment: apologies, the option select forms part of a navbar for viewports 480px and below (mobile devices) I want to make an ajax request when clicking on an option  to show different content

Comment: Then put id on the option and then in application.js do something like: $("#id_of_the_option").click or onclik and in the function do what you want to do - show different content

Comment: could i use .load when rendering a rails partial, so click function followed by load function